# font_size of a button changes depending to the size of its widget(button)

Tags: python, kivy-language

**## Background:**

I'm designing a layout and decided to make the font_size of a Button in the Layout change depending on the width of its Button (which size also changes depending to the canvas/Layout).

**## Problem:**

It's great, until the button width gets bigger making the font_size also get bigger, exceeding the button size. And that's what I want to avoid.

**## What I'm trying to do:**

What I have in mind is to stop making the font_size change depending the width of its Button when it exceeds a certain value. Problem is, i don't know how to implement it.

*// I'm really sorry if the title is misleading but idk what else to title it, english isn't my native language.*

**## What I've tried doing:**

I've tried doing: "self.font_size", "font_size", and "butt.font_size"

(taking the value of the font_size and putting it in an "if" statement)

but i just don't know how to acquire the value nor use an if statement in kvlang.

**## Builder File:**

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .59, .74, .20
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    Button:
        id : butt
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.8, 'center_y':.1}
        size_hint: .2, .07
        background_normal: ''
        background_color: 1, 1, .8, 1
        color: 0.15, .5, 0.2, 1
        text: "NEXT"
        font_size: 0.15 * self.width
        on_press:
            print("pressed, navigating to next screen")"
```